# Dictionary saved to NSUserDefaults always returns nil

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to save a dictionary to NSUserDefaults using the `setObject()` function but when I use the `objectForKey()` function to retrieve the dictionary it returns `nil`. Why is this happening?

```
var data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();
var scoreboard = [Int : String]()
let scores = "scoresKey"

scoreboard[3] = "spencer"
scoreboard[6] = "brooke"
scoreboard[11] = "jason"

data.setObject(scoreboard, forKey: scores)
data.objectForKey(scores) // Returns nil
```

Comment: You need to test it on a real project. Not playground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem was that **it's not possible to use NSUserDefaults in a Playground.**

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31210205/3498950

A second problem is found when the code above runs in a normal iOS project. It throws an `NSInvalidArgumentException` since the dictionary was a non-property list object because the keys needed to be of type String.

> Although NSDictionary and CFDictionary objects allow their keys to be
>   objects of any type, if the keys are not string objects, the
>   collections are not property-list objects.

See: "[What is a Property List?](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-54303)" in the Apple Docs

Comment: Did you try the exact code above? It doesn't work for me. It throws an exception: "Attempt to set a non-property-list object {
    6 = brooke;
    3 = spencer;
    11 = jason;
} as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key scoresKey".

Comment: (Which is because "property-list" dictionaries must have strings as keys. See ["What is a property list?"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-54303) in the Apple docs, and also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704678/nsdictionary-with-nsnumber-to-nsstring-mapping-is-non-property-list-object).)